Animating atomic orbitals of the hydrogen atom in Python
I have a question regarding simulating the hydrogen atom and the atomic orbitals.
So I wanted to mess around a little bit with sliders in Python and I figured, that an animation of the atomic orbitals for different n, l and m values would be ideal. The part with the sliders was easy, and I could just stop there, but I am too determined in figuring out why I get wrong results.
In the following, you can find my code:
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import sph_harm, eval_genlaguerre
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
import math

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Initial values for the quantum numbers
n_init = 1
l_init = 0
m_init = 0

# Arrays for the spherical coordinates
phi = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 150)
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 150)
R = np.linspace(0, 20, 150)

PHI, THETA = np.meshgrid(phi, theta)

surf = ax.plot_surface(np.array([[]]), np.array([[]]), np.array([[]]), color='0.75')

ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
ax.set_zlim(-1, 1)

# Sliders for the quantum numbers
n_freq = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
l_freq = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
m_freq = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.05, 0.65, 0.03])
n_slider = Slider(ax=n_freq, label='n', valmin=1, valmax=10, valinit=n_init, valstep=1)
l_slider = Slider(ax=l_freq, label='l', valmin=0, valmax=n_slider.valmax - 1, valinit=l_init, valstep=1)
m_slider = Slider(ax=m_freq, label='m', valmin=-l_slider.valmax, valmax=l_slider.valmax, valinit=m_init, valstep=1)

# Update the plot when the sliders are changed
def update(val):
    n = int(n_slider.val)
    l = int(l_slider.val)
    
    l_slider.valmax = n - 1
    if l > l_slider.valmax:
        l_slider.set_val(l_slider.valmax)
        l = l_slider.valmax
        
    m_slider.valmax = l
    m_slider.valmin = -l
    if int(m_slider.val) > l:
        m_slider.set_val(l)
    if int(m_slider.val) < -l:
        m_slider.set_val(-l)

    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

n_slider.on_changed(update)
l_slider.on_changed(update)
m_slider.on_changed(update)

# Introducing a reset button for the sliders
resetax = fig.add_axes([0.08, 0.065, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', hovercolor='0.975')

def reset(event):
    l_slider.reset()
    m_slider.reset()
    n_slider.reset()
    
button.on_clicked(reset)

# Function to calculate the radial component of the wave function
def R_nl(r, n, l):
    a_0 = 1
    rho = 2 * r / (n * a_0)
    normalization = np.sqrt((2 / (n * a_0))**3 * math.factorial(n - l - 1) / (2 * n * math.factorial(n + l)))
    radial_component = normalization * np.exp(-rho / 2) * rho**l * eval_genlaguerre(n - l - 1, 2 * l + 1, rho)
    return radial_component

def animate(i):
    global surf
    t = 2 * np.pi * i / nframes
    
    n = int(n_slider.val)
    l = int(l_slider.val)
    m = int(m_slider.val)
    
    R_vals = R_nl(R, n, l)
    Y_vals = sph_harm(m, l, THETA, PHI)
    psi = R_vals * Y_vals
    psi_t = psi * np.exp(-1j * t)
    prob_density = np.abs(psi_t)**2
    prob_density /= np.max(prob_density)
    
    X = prob_density * np.sin(THETA) * np.cos(PHI)
    Y = prob_density * np.sin(THETA) * np.sin(PHI)
    Z = prob_density * np.cos(THETA)
    
    surf.remove()
    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=4, cstride=4, cmap='coolwarm')
    
nframes = 36


anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=nframes + 1, interval=2000 / (nframes + 1))
plt.show()

Obviously when executing the code I get no animation since I take the absolute value of the exponential function which just equals one. My result looks like this:

which are quite different from the expected results.

I think, that my problem is somewhere in calculating the radial part.
I mainly tried different scipy functions for the Laguerre polynomials and spherical harmonics but it didn't change anything.
